# Quick Time player records screen very quickly?

Tags: macos, screen, recording

I use Screen Recording feature in Quick Time player for some purposes, but when I record my screen it records the screen actions very fast.Is there any way to chnge this to normal?

Eg.

If I move my cursor normally also while recording my screen it records it as if I am moving it in lightning speed.

Comment: Is the whole video playing back faster? Or is the framerate just very low and thus creating the illusion of a fast "jumping" cursor?

Comment: No when I just click cl mormally on new screen record then click record, then if I even move my hand on the track pad slowly it gets records it very fast like if I miss be it slowly up in the video it seems like it is moving fast up